# Is Enterprise Library 4.1 and server 2008 sp2 compatible? I can't find specifics on this

Tags: windows-server-2008, enterprise-library

What I thought would be an easy google turned up no results. I'm trying to find out if Enterprise Library 4.1 is compatible with Windows Server 2008 SP2.

The system requirements say its compatible with Server 2008, but there is no mention of the service pack. Does anyone know definitively if these two are compatible?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Typically compatibilities will list the minimum requirements; compatible with "Windows Server 2008" would include it and subsequent service packs (unless explicitly indicated otherwise). Keep in mind EL 4.1 was released almost a year before 2k8 SP2 was.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know definitively if these two are compatible?

I guess it would depend on how you define "definitively" and "compatible".  ;)

Do you want to know if Enterprise Library will run under Windows 2008 Server SP2?  I don't believe that it was formally tested against that version (typically testing will go back two OS releases and SP2 didn't come out until the year after Enterprise Library was released) but it should work on later OS versions.  For example, I have used version 4.1 with Windows 7.